# VUEX SSR: Как динамически зарегистрировать модуль?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать модуль динамически, опираясь на документация VUE SSR,
но при рендеринге на клиенте получаю ошибку:

> [vuex] module namespace not found in mapGetters(): admin-layout/

Как исправить ошибку?

```
import {
    name as layoutName,
    module as layoutModule
} from "~admin/modules/layout/store/module";
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
    asyncData({ store }) {
        store.registerModule(layoutName, layoutModule);

        return store.dispatch(`${layoutName}/FETCH_MAIN_PAGE`);
    },

    destroyed () {
        this.$store.unregisterModule(layoutName);
    },

    computed: mapGetters(layoutName, [
        "tree"
    ]),


    components: { TreeItemComponent: () => import("~admin/template/components/tree-item.vue") }
};
```

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html#namespacing
во vuex нужно прописать namespaced: true

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки уже есть ответ)

> [vuex] module namespace not found in mapGetters(): admin-layout/

Ваш модуль зарегистрирован в глобальном пространстве имён. Вам нужно создать модуль с собственным пространством имён. (Добавить `namespaced: true`)

Подробнее по ссылке:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/modules.html#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD

Так же посмотрите vuexok для типизации стора.